# Factorial Algorithm which uses no Big-Integer library

Tags: c#, algorithm, biginteger, factorial

I'm studing computer engineering and we have a hard task.

We have to develop a C# application which can calculate factorial of really big numbers without *BIGINT* . I mean really big numbers, like *123564891...82598413!* . And we don't have to use permission for use custom libraries (like *BIGINT*) .

Researched it and found a few questions like this, but **this question different than others because** we have to calculate *really big numbers without any custom libraries*. I found [PoorMans Algorithm](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/csharp/FactorialPoorMans.cs.html) . But it's calculating up to 10000 . It's not enough for us.

With my teammates, we found a solution . Let's say we will get factorial of 123 . We will get 123 as String . And then , we will sum 123 , 122 times (it's equal to 123 x 122) . And then sum result 121 times. It will goes like this until reach to 1. So, we will sum two strings.

We create an algorithm for summing strings. We are getting last char of the first number (3 of 123) as an integer (we can use integer, but not bigint) . And get last char of second number as integer (2 of 122). Sum them and found result number's last char (result = x...x5) . We will do it from last char to first char. Finally we will get the *result number*. But as you know, we should use a while() or for() loop, and for use this loop we need bigint again.

```
String number = "9878945647978979798798797189"; //we will get factorial of this
for(int i = 0;i < number.Length; i++)
{
   // sum all chars one by one
}
```

we can't use a loop like this, because `i` variable will be exceed range of integer and we will get error. So we have to use bigint here. I hope i explained it.

*Now here my question*, walkthroughs for creating an algorithm which can calculate factorial of really big numbers without using BIGINT .

It's programmer question, not Math.stackexchange.com question, because i need programmatical answers and walkthroughs directly. If i ask this question on Math site, they will give me this list : http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm . Probably they won't understand my '*BIGINT problem*' .

Comment: I think the exercise is asking you to write your own bigint library.

Comment: Do you understand that number of digits grows really fast, you will not even be able to store all digits of your number in example. Also it will take really long.

Comment: @Andrey , exactly! that's the problem :) Because of this our application will contain a timer , and we will show user how many seconds it's took. Also for example we will store result of 123! and when user ask 124! we will use directly 124*123! .

Comment: @RaymondChen , Probably you mean same with this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2217956/556169 Can you recommend any other resource?

Comment: @Eray what do you expect from us? write it for you? (I see no question mark in your post) Otherwise, as a computer engineering student, you can implement your own BitInt class. I guess you have already read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth's_multiplication_algorithm)

Comment: @Eray some simple BigInt for this case can be implemented relatively easy, why not just to do it? You even don't need subtraction and division.

Comment: @I4V , I'm expecting some good resources , links and ideas from you, like you're doing, thank you :) Because i hadn't any idea, where should i start . Now i have some ideas. Andrey, not sure i have enough technical knowledge. I'll work on it.

Comment: *Really sorry for this 3th flood comment* but of course i'm not expecting from you writing algorithm for me. I'm doing researches for 2 days. But not found enough information. While i was asking this question, i hadn't any idea about this subject. Now i have some ideas, this was exactly what i expect from you :) If someone send these as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: `"9878945647978979798798797189"; //we will get factorial of this`. Assuming you can make 1 billion multiplications per second :),
it would take ~313,259,311,516 years.

Comment: If you've been stumped for two days, you might want to visit your professor or TA.

Comment: @I4V , just checked professor's task document again. He's saying , "program must be able to calculate everything." As you see, it's not explanatory :)

Comment: In shortly, application shouldn't have any number limit.

Comment: @Eray I may have made a mistake, I can be only 31 billion years..

Comment: Professor will check only codes :) (i hope) He won't wait for 31 billion years

Comment: Really still waiting for someone who send this conversations as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to write your own big-integer library. Check Knuth Volume 2 to get started.

Your expectations look a little bit ... over-enthusiastic. You will *not* be able to calculate the factorial of 9878945647978979798798797189 no matter what you do.

Comment: yes it's a little over-enthusiatstic, i meant program shouldn't have any limits.